# Function from $\omega_1$ to $\omega$: $\exists n\in\omega~(\cup f^{-1}(n)=\omega_1)$

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Let $f:\omega_1\to\omega.$ Why must there exist $n\in\omega$ such that $\cup f^{-1}(n)=\omega_1?$ Why must there exist $m\in\omega$ such that $\cap f^{-1}(m)=0?$

This problem seems related to cofinality. The two parts seem related, and perhaps once we prove one part it will be clear how to prove the other part. I first conjectured that $f$ has to be bounded, but that's (very) false; for example, the function
$$f:\omega_1\to\omega:x\mapsto\begin{cases}x&\text{if }x<\omega,\\0&\text{else}\end{cases}$$
is unbounded. In addition, I conjectured that taking $m=f(0)+1$ might work for the second part, but I got lost/confused as I was trying to prove that and also I suspect that it doesn't actually work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sets $f^{-1}[\{n\}]$ partition $\omega_1$ into countably many parts. The union of countably many countable parts would be countable, so at least one of those parts must be uncountable. That is, there must be an $n\in\omega$ such that $f^{-1}[\{n\}]$ is uncountable and hence cofinal in $\omega_1$. But $f^{-1}[\{n\}]\subseteq f^{-1}[n+1]$, so $f^{-1}[n+1]$ is cofinal in $\omega_1$, and its union is therefore $\omega_1$.

For the second part of the question, let $n=f(0)$; then $$0\in f^{-1}[\{n\}]\subseteq f^{-1}[n+1]\;,$$ so $\bigcap f^{-1}[n+1]=0$.

Comment: I actually meant $f^{-1}[n],$ not $f^{-1}[\{n\}].$

Comment: @xFioraMstr18: Okay; I’ll modify my answer accordingly. It doesn’t really change anything.

Comment: Why does $f^{-1}[\{n\}]$ being uncountable imply it's cofinal in $\omega_1$? I have seen the converse implication before, but this one is new to me.

Comment: @xFioraMstr18: Because if the set were not cofinal, there would be some $\alpha\in\omega_1$ such that $f^{-1}[\{n\}]\subseteq\alpha$, but that’s impossible: each $\alpha\in\omega_1$ has only countably many predecessors.